# Microphone becomes inactive when I open a new project in cubase

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, cubase, windows, asio

I just bought a CAD USB microphone .Now using ASIO for all i managed to get it connected in CUBASE 5 and I can see the bars moving when i tap the microphone . But as soon as i open a new project the microphone becomes inactive .Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I dont use Cubase but if its like other DAW's the problem is most likely this,

Generally when a new track (or project with new tracks) is added to a DAW (at least in digital performer) its muted and set to the default input. You have to select the input for the track (in your case the CAD) and un-mute it to hear it. Most DAW's allow you to set up a default track template that when the track is created it will adhere to that template. If you set it to always use your CAD as the input and un-mute the tracks you should see it.

You may also have to select the CAD as your input when you create a new project, again most DAW's allow you to set your default input so setting the CAD as default should do the trick.

This is all a best guess others confirm please.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be an ASIO driver problem. I was having a sound issue a couple days ago with FL Studio and all I needed to was toggle some of the settings.

i found the solution for my problem with the video below, it's for FL Studio but if you imitate the instructions on Cubase you shouldn't have a problem. Let me know if you figure it out or not, i dont mind helping because i know how frustrating it is working with ASIO drivers...

http://youtube.com/watch?v=cbabtLVeP5Q

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Cubase 5. I'm now on Cubase 8.5, but from what I can remembers - you'll need to go into your VST connections settings and set the correct input as the USB microphone.

I normally create a blank project and set all of my program settings to match and work with whatever hardware I have. I then save that project as a template. When starting a new project simply select that template and all of your settings will from the base project will be loaded- granted that you have the correct hardware attached to your PC.